# Node in linked-list in C language

Tags: c, string-comparison, c-strings, function-definition

I start learning linked lists.
My problem is that the conditional statement is not working. Here is the problem code.

```
'''
Node* search_word(Node* head, Word target)
{
Node*p=head;
while(p != NULL)
{
    if(p->data.name==target.name)
    {
        printf("%s founded", target.name);
        return p;
    };
    p=p->nextNodeAddress;
};
printf("There is no %s. \n", target.name);
return NULL;
}

'''
```

Here is my full source code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

#### # create struct named Word that have char name[100]

```
typedef struct Word 
{
    char name[100];
} Word;
```

#### # create struct named Node

```
typedef struct node
{
 
Word data;

struct node* nextNodeAddress;
} Node;
```

#### # Function that can insert node to the first of list

```
Node* insert_first(Node*head, Word newData)
{
    Node* p=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->data = newData;
    p->nextNodeAddress=head;
    head=p;
    return head;
};
```

#### # Function that can print out list

```
void print_listedNode(Node* head)
{
    for(Node* i=head; i!=NULL; i=i->nextNodeAddress)
    {
        printf("%s->", i->data.name);
    };
    printf("NULL\n");
}
```

#### # Function that can search word  (conditional statement is not working. But no error.)

```
Node* search_word(Node* head, Word target)
{
    Node*p=head;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        if(p->data.name==target.name)
        {
            printf("%s founded", target.name);
            return p;
        };
        p=p->nextNodeAddress;
    };
    printf("There is no %s. \n", target.name);
    return NULL;
}
```

#### # int main()

```
int main(int argv, char* argc)

{
    Node* head = NULL;
    Word data;

strcpy(data.name, "APPLE");
head = insert_first(head, data);
print_listedNode(head);

strcpy(data.name, "LEMON");
head = insert_first(head, data);
print_listedNode(head);

strcpy(data.name, "BANANA");
head = insert_first(head, data);
print_listedNode(head);

strcpy(data.name, "BANANA");
head = search_word(head, data);
print_listedNode(head);
return 0;
}
```

and the result is

```
APPLE->NULL
LEMON->APPLE->NULL
BANANA->LEMON->APPLE->NULL
There is no BANANA.
NULL
```

I expect to get

```
 APPLE->NULL
 LEMON->APPLE->NULL
 BANANA->LEMON->APPLE->NULL
 BANANA founded
 BANANA->LEMON->APPLE->NULL
```

Thank you for reading the eye-breaking code.

Comment: you're using `p->data.name==target.name` which will not work in `C`. It'll compare the pointers there. use the function [strncmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncmp).

Comment: @Hrant No, one should use `strcmp` here and not `strncmp`.

Answer (score 1):

In this if statement

```
if(p->data.name==target.name)
```

there are compared two pointers (after the implicit conversion of the array designators to pointers to their first elements) instead of the strings pointed to by the pointers.

You need to write

```
if( strcmp( p->data.name, target.name ) == 0 )
```